# This needs to be reprinted vs. this needs reprinted

Tags: grammar, word-usage

What is the difference between using:

- this needs to be fixed; and
- this needs fixed

Can they be used interchangeably?
Is the second one grammatically correct?

Comment: I'm not sure even Western Pennsylvanians would endorse *needs reprinted* - but regardless of what *they* might say, the usage is definitely "non-standard".

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: "This needs to be fixed" is correct. Don't use "This needs fixed."

Longer, more interesting answer: Ordinarily, you must use *to be* with a past participle such as *fixed*. However, in certain parts of the United States there is a [peculiar regional practice](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/455576?uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21103381544847) of omitting *to be* when using *needs* or *wants* with a past participle, and in those areas, "this needs fixed" is exactly the kind of sentence you would expect to hear. You would never want to use this construction for general consumption, however.